# Passing a custom class as a primitive data type reference

Tags: c++

**The problem**

I have a custom class that is like a extended version of a primitive type, what I want is to pass it throught a method parameter (as a reference but it's using the stored type, not the class type).

**Example Code**

```
/* example of the extended class, just a skeleton to show the purpose */
class INT 
{
public:
    INT() : _value(0) {}
    INT(const std::int32_t& value) : _value(value) {}
...
private:
    std::int32_t _value;
};

/* example method that takes int ref parameter */
static std::int32_t sum(const std::int32_t& lhs, const std::int32_t& rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int main()
{
    INT a, b;
    a = 15;
    b = 20;

    /* the usage example */
    std::int32_t result = sum(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Is this possible? I've looking and studying operator overloading but I didn't find a way to do this.

What i have tryied is creating a method that returns the reference to the inner `_value`, this solves the problem, but what i want is to pass without calling a method to get the inner reference.

Comment: `operator std::int32_t() const noexcept { return _value; }`

Comment: Why not simply create a class for the type and define all the methods and operator overloads you need?

Comment: @wcochran yeah, in the full version of the example class i started implement it all, but i didn't know that i could overload like Stephen said.